# tooltip remove to just one function

Tags: javascript, jquery, tooltip, jquery-tools

I need to do this

```
$('.tooltip').remove();
```

but just for this class.

```
$('.fav[title]');
```

I have tried

```
$('.fav[title]').('.tooltip').remove();
```

or

```
$('.fav[title] tooltip').remove();
```

Both are obviously wrong, how the syntax for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use:

```
$('.tooltip.fav[title]').remove();
```

Answer (score 1):

I think what you need is to remove the `.fav[title]` which is having the tooptip class, if so then try

```
$('.fav.tooltip[title]').remove();
```